# How to switch the if else condition based on one command

Tags: conditionals

I will try to code the if or else condition working based on the one command **\sectiontype{}** command

**Case 1:**

If the \sectiontype{} command is available in the tex file below mentioned code is executed

```
\artsubmitted{\textbf{Section Title} The article was submitted to \@sectiontype}
```

**Case 2:**

If the \sectiontype{} command is available in the tex file below mentioned code is executed

```
\artsubmitted{The article was submitted to Jounal Division}
```

MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{authblk}

    \makeatletter

    \newcommand\editedhead{\raggedright \textbf{Edited by:}\break}

    \let\@editor\@empty
    \newcommand{\editor}[1]{\protected@edef\@editor{\@editor #1\par}}

    \def\@artsubmitted{}
    \def\artsubmitted#1{%
         \gdef\@artsubmitted{\raggedright  #1}}

    \def\@sectiontype{}
    \def\sectiontype#1{%
         \gdef\@sectiontype{\raggedright #1}}

    \sectiontype{Fuel Cells}


\ifx\@sectiontype\@empty
\artsubmitted{{The article was submitted to Jounal Division}}
\else
\artsubmitted{\textbf{Section Title}: The article was submitted to \@sectiontype}
\fi

    \def\@maketitle{%
      \newpage
      \null
    \vbox to \textheight{\vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{12pc}%\vfill%
    \hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{10pc}
    {\editedhead\par}
    {\@editor\par}%
    {\@artsubmitted}
    \end{minipage}}}
    \hspace*{11pc}
    \vbox to \textheight{\vspace*{-44pc}%
    \hbox to 10pc{\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{31pc}  
      \let \footnote \thanks
        {\@title \par}%
        \vskip 1.5em%   
        {\large
          \lineskip .5em%
          \begin{tabular}[t]{l}%
            \raggedright\@author
          \end{tabular}\par}%
       \end{minipage}}}}%
      \par
      \vskip 8.5em}

    \makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \title{Hormonal crosstalk for root development}
    \author[1]{Author One}
    \author[2]{Author Two}
    \author[2]{Author Three}
    \affil[1]{Author Address}
    \editor{Editor A and Editor address}
    \editor{Editor B and Editor address}
    \editor{Editor C and Editor address}
    \maketitle

    \end{document}
```

The below mentioned command execute successfully in tex file preamble Space. But the Same coding does not work the article.cls file. I don't know what is the reason?

```
    \ifx\@sectiontype\@empty
\artsubmitted{{The article was submitted to Jounal Division}}
\else
\artsubmitted{\textbf{Section Title}: The article was submitted to \@sectiontype}
\fi
```

Comment: I can not guess what your edited comment means. I hope you don't mean that you are editing the article.cls file? You should not do that. It would make your latex system incompatible with latex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
\if\@sectiontype
```

`\if` is true if the first two non expandable tokens after expansion are equal characters.

`\@sectiontype` is expandable with definition

```
\raggedright Fuel cells
```

So it expands `\raggedright`

which isdefined by

```
\def\raggedright{%
  \let\\
  .....}
```

So it is going to compare `\let` with the first non expandable token in the definition of `\\`

where `\\` is defined by

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\\{%
  \let \reserved@e \relax
```

So the definition of `\\` starts with `\protect` which is `\relax` so the test is `\if\let\relax` which is two non-characters which counts as true.

However the remaining tokens from the expansions just done are now in the input stream so
in particular the expansion of `\\` has the tokens from

```
\def\@gnewline #1{%
  \ifvmode
    \@nolnerr
  \else
    \unskip \reserved@e {\reserved@f#1}\nobreak \hfil \break
  \fi}
```

In the preamble you are in vmode so it starts off by giving the no-line error.

---

You don't say exactly what you wanted to do but I suspect you want the test

```
\ifx\@sectiontype\@empty
```

which tests without expansion whether the two commands have the same definition, which they will if `\@sectiontype` has its original `{}` definition.

Comment: \ifx\@sectiontype\@empty This condition is perfectly match my required output. But This condition is only execute tex file preamble space. If i declare the condtion article.cls file the condition is not working. Kindly advice

Comment: @Vetri sorry I do not understand your comment. Perhaps you should edit the question with some example code that is not working

Comment: @Carlisle I edit and save my question. Please advice